# How to change the background of a sticky section header view?

Tags: uitableview

In a UITableView, I want the section header view changes background as soon as it sticks to the top, as demonstrated in Apple's Music and Photos app.

For example, in Apple's Music app, when you are in the section "Songs", you see a list of songs in alphabet order. Each section header view contains a letter. When a section header view reaches to the top, its background changes from white to gray. When the header is no longer at top, its background returns to white.

Anyone knows how to achieve this effect?